# How can I catch key press in java while working with selenium geckodriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was working with javafx and I could do something like this

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCode());
        //do something
    }       
});
```

to get all the key press while my app has the focus.

Is there a way to do the same while working with selenium? I dont want to send something to the browser, I just want, for example, if I press `ctrl+q` execute `driver.quit()` and close everything.

Comment: so far there is no such support given by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 

    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CTRL); 
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q); 
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CTRL); 
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
```

should do the job.

Comment: What Im suppose to do with this?